# Test if number is inside circular interval

Tags: math, language-agnostic, numbers

Let us suppose we have a number circle, that ranges from -180 to 180, looking something like this:

```
         180/-180
           ***
         *** ***
    90 ***     *** -90
         *** ***
           ***
            0
```

A section of the circle is always swept in a clockwise direction. How can you tell if a number is inside or outside of the interval swept?

In the following sample I/O, the first two numbers represent the interval and the third number is the number being checked. Output is true if the point is (inclusively) inside the interval, false otherwise.

```
2 4 6
False
2 4 4
True
90 -90 0
False
90 -90 -180
True
```

Comment: so all these intervals in the sample I/O check against the -180/180 circle?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Normalize your numbers from 0 to 359.  Consider the arguments a, b and c (is c inside the sweep of a -> b).  *As pointed out by Chris Cunningham, you can also normalize to -180 to +179; see discussion below.  The important part of normalization is to make sure only one number refers to each point on the circle.*
- If `(a <= b)` then return `(c >= a && c <= b)`
- else you've swept across the 0 point and should return <strike>`(c >= b || c <= a)`</strike> `(c >= a || c <= b)`

Comment: I would say: `if (a > b) then return (c >= a || c <= b)`. Example: a = 270, b = 90, c = 300, should return `true` (c in a->b).

Comment: @Jiri: You're right, I have updated the answer with the correct variables.

Comment: @Chris, main reason is that 180/-180 refer to the same point, so (170, 180, -180) should return true.  If it's also necessary to treat 270/-90 as equal, normalizing fixes that.  Finally, it's easier to do the range checking in a case of -90 to -140 (which covers -90, 0, 90, 180, -180, -140.

Comment: @tomlogic I agree that he needs to get rid of issues where the same location is referenced by two different numbers; since he preferred -180 to 180, I guess I would have told him to normalize the numbers from -180 to +179. It turns out it's a minor quibble; removing my -1. Edit: Apparently you can't remove downvotes unless the answer is edited. I learn something new every day... :/

Comment: @Chris, minor but fair quibble.  I've edited my answer with a note regarding your normalization comments.

Answer (score 1):

All the points x that are in [a,b] verifies :

if a%360<=b%360:

`(x)%360<=b%360 and x%360>=a%360` if you process in the direct sens.

otherwise your intervall contains 0, and you can just verify. x in[a,b]

therefore:

```
def f(x,a,b):
    if a%360<=b%360:
        return ((x)%360<=b%360 and x%360>=a%360)
    else:
        return b>=x>=a
```

does what you need.

```
>>> f(0,90,-90)
False
>>> f(-180,90,-90)
True
>>> f(4,2,4)
True
>>> f(6,2,4)
False
```

I might inverse some things.. so you wil may be need to check it again.

Comment: I guess this only works in languages where negative numbers are converted to positive ones on modulo operations. Because `-4%10 = -4` is true too. In this case you would have to test whether the number is still negative and subtract it from 360.

Comment: Yes, you're right. if this function can return a negative number, you will need to define the positive remain of the euclidian division by 360 in another function.

Comment: @Ricky Bobby: How is `x<=b and x>=a` different from `b>=x>=a`?  I think your logic is a mixed up version of my answer...

Comment: @tomlogic: Yes you're right. I first wrote only the first test: x)%360<=b%360 and x%360>=a%360 and I realise afterwards it was not sufficient. the only difference here is that my test is on a%360<=b%360  (not equivalent to a<=b) but the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have `start` and `end` as endpoints of the intervall.

```
range = 360
if start > end:
    if number > start:
        end += range
    else:
        start -= range
inside = (number >= start) and (number <= end)
```