# How do I calculate the opening days of online stores with different working days.?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am having trouble automatically calculating the working days of different online stores that open at different days. The difficulty here is some of the stores open during the weekends. What i realized was JavaScript starts counting the days of the week from **0** which is a Sunday.

```
example
store A, WORKING_DAYS = Tue - Sun
store B, WORKING_DAYS = Mon - Fri
store C, WORKING_DAYS = Mon - Tue
store D, WORKING_DAYS = Fri - Mon
```

```
    //  0 (sunday) - 6 (saturday)  give day is thursay which is 4
    // workdays fri - tues, ie 5 - 2 but current day is saturday and we 
    looking at positive values
    if( dayStart < currentDay < dayEnd){
        return(
            <Text style={[styles.h4,styles.tag,  {backgroundColor:'#4eae5c'}]}>open</Text>
            )
        }
    if(currentDay) {
        return(
            <Text style={[styles.h4,styles.tag, 
        {backgroundColor:'red'}]}>closed</Text>
            )
        }
```

because Sunday returns **0** from JavaScript date, how do you find the interval between **Friday** and **Monday**

Comment: Please show us the code you have written that you need help with.

Comment: ok... will edit it and add just now. Basically trying to do what google does with telling you if a business is open or closed when you look it up on google. So even without checking the time you know whether the shop is open or closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You state that you want to determine whether an online store is open on a specific weekday, given that you know which weekday it opens and which weekday it closes. Days are numbered from 0 (Sunday) to 6 (Saturday). This gets challenging when a store opens on Friday (5) and closes on Monday (1).

A straightforward solution is the one given in [the answer by otw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63084819/6738706):

```
if(dayStart is less than dayEnd) {
  check whether currentDay >= dayStart and currentDay <= dayEnd
} else {
  check whether currentDay <= dayStart or currentDay >= dayEnd
}
```

Another solution is to view the weekdays as a [ring of integers modulo 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n). We can then use [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) to check whether a number *n* is in the interval [*a*, *b*] with the following inequality, even when *a* is larger than *b*:

> (*n* - *a*) mod 7 <= (*b* - *a*) mod 7

To solve your specific problem, we can define an `isOpen()` function like this:

```js
function isOpen(currentDay, dayStart, dayEnd){
  return mod(currentDay - dayStart, 7) <= mod(dayEnd - dayStart, 7); 
}

function mod(a, n){
  return (a % n + n) % n; // guarantees positive modulo operation
}
```

Then, you can call this function in your code like this:

```js
if(isOpen(currentDay, dayStart, dayEnd)) {
  return (
    <Text style={[styles.h4, styles.tag, {backgroundColor: '#4eae5c'}]}>open</Text>
  );
} else {
  return (
    <Text style={[styles.h4, styles.tag, {backgroundColor: 'red'}]}>closed</Text>
  );
}
```

Comment: Love this, I was trying so hard to remember that modulo technique as well but I hadn't used it in years! Very well explained!

Comment: Thank you so much for your code. Sorry I wasn't able to reply early. Was caught up with some other things. I am very grateful. Your code works really well. Thank you so much for your help @otw. Truly grateful

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. `day` is the day you are checking, `open` is the first day open and `close` is the last day open of the week.

I am just using moment to convert the plain text names into numbers but you could easily map that to an array or something.

This code is basically a variation of this answer: [Test if number is inside circular interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613718/test-if-number-is-inside-circular-interval/6613931)

Basically you just check if your open day is smaller than or equal to your close day.

If it is, then you have a normal range and are just checking if your day is greater than the open day AND smaller than the close day to see if it is open on that day.

If you open day is greater than your close day, that means your range is going to be starting its count over so you actually need to check if your day is greater than or equal to your open day OR less than or equal to your close day to see if it is open.

```js
function isStoreOpen(day, open, close) {

  const dayNum = moment().day(day).day();
  const openNum = moment().day(open).day();
  const closeNum = moment().day(close).day();

  if(openNum <= closeNum) {
    return (dayNum >= openNum && dayNum <= closeNum);
  } else {
    return (dayNum >= openNum || dayNum <= closeNum);
  }

}

// store A, WORKING_DAYS = Tue - Sun
console.log("Store A (Tue - Sun) is open on Wednesday: " + isStoreOpen("Wednesday", "Tuesday", "Sunday"));

// store B, WORKING_DAYS = Mon - Fri
console.log("Store B (Mon - Fri) is open on Wednesday: " + isStoreOpen("Wednesday", "Monday", "Friday"));

// store C, WORKING_DAYS = Mon - Tue
console.log("Store C (Mon - Tue) is open on Wednesday: " + isStoreOpen("Wednesday", "Monday", "Tuesday"));

// store D, WORKING_DAYS = Fri - Mon
console.log("Store D (Fri - Mon) is open on Wednesday: " + isStoreOpen("Wednesday", "Friday", "Monday"));
console.log("Store D (Fri - Mon) is open on Saturday: " + isStoreOpen("Saturday", "Friday", "Monday"));
console.log("Store D (Fri - Mon) is open on Friday: " + isStoreOpen("Friday", "Friday", "Monday"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Here is an example with something closer to your code:

```js
function isStoreOpen(currentDay, dayStart, dayEnd) {
  if (dayStart <= dayEnd) {
    if (currentDay >= dayStart && currentDay <= dayEnd) {
      return "open"
    } else {
      return "closed"
    }
  } else {
    if (currentDay >= dayStart || currentDay <= dayEnd) {
      return "open"
    } else {
      return "closed"
    }
  }
}

// store A, WORKING_DAYS = Tue - Sun
console.log("Store A (Tue - Sun) status on Wednesday: " + isStoreOpen(4, 2, 0));

// store B, WORKING_DAYS = Mon - Fri
console.log("Store B (Mon - Fri) status on Wednesday: " + isStoreOpen(4, 1, 5));

// store C, WORKING_DAYS = Mon - Tue
console.log("Store C (Mon - Tue) status open on Wednesday: " + isStoreOpen(4, 1, 2));

// store D, WORKING_DAYS = Fri - Mon
console.log("Store D (Fri - Mon) status on Wednesday: " + isStoreOpen(4, 5, 1));
console.log("Store D (Fri - Mon) status on Saturday: " + isStoreOpen(6, 5, 1));
console.log("Store D (Fri - Mon) status on Friday: " + isStoreOpen(5, 5, 1));
```

Your exact implementation might look something like this:

```js
if (dayStart <= dayEnd) {
  if (currentDay >= dayStart && currentDay <= dayEnd) {
            return(<Text style={[styles.h4,styles.tag,  {backgroundColor:'#4eae5c'}]}>open</Text>);
  } else {
            return(<Text style={[styles.h4,styles.tag,{backgroundColor:'red'}]}>closed</Text>);
  }
} else {
  if (currentDay >= dayStart || currentDay <= dayEnd) {
            return(<Text style={[styles.h4,styles.tag,  {backgroundColor:'#4eae5c'}]}>open</Text>);
  } else {
            return(<Text style={[styles.h4,styles.tag,{backgroundColor:'red'}]}>closed</Text>);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have been coding for roughly 6 months now but I have an app on PlayStore with 100+ downloads. I am a junior developer and learnt everything I know through Youtube and online materials. Could you please explain to me how to use the code.

I don't understand
    const dayNum = moment().day(day).day();
how to I implement this code in my code

Comment: @Kweku moment is just a library I am using to convert the plain text day to numbers like in your example. You don't have to use it but here is the docs: https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/02-get-set/06-day/

Comment: @Kweku I added another code example that is closer to using the code you shared.